# Why is the empty div moving the div with content?

Tags: html, css

I dont understand why is the empty div moving the div with the content.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>a</div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: The empty div has difficulty determining the position of its baseline. Solution: align them to one another by setting the vertical-align property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `vertical-align` to them:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top; /* <-- SEE THIS? */
}
```

```html
<div>a</div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Oh, you answered the question after it was closed. Well done. Have an upvote.

Comment: @MrLister - Thank you for the upvote on my junk.

Answer (score 1):

Change the style

```
    div { 
width: 100px; 
height: 100px; 
background-color: red; 
border: 2px solid #000; 
float:left; 
margin:0 2px;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/anwnacc2/

please check th jsfiddle

Comment: div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  float:left;
  margin:0 2px;
}

use this style it will make the divs side by side